# Where is the php file of single member profile view (BuddyPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

The edit.php file is for single member rdit profile page.

And I'm looking for the page that handle single member profile view. So the I can modify the display of user's profile view.

Is there someone knows where is the .php file that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default file is in:

> /wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/profile.php

If you want to make changes to the file, remember to make a copy in your child theme in the following directory:

> /wp-content/themes/your-theme-name-child/buddypress/members/single/profile.php